# C Program cant create Text files

Tags: c

I know java already and decided to pick up C today. I am trying to do a beginner exercise where I take two text files and generate a 3rd text file with the content of the first 2 text files.

I created a folder on my desktop and the only files in it are file1.txt, file2.txt, merge.c, merge.exe.

This is the contents of merge.c below

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
 
   FILE *fp1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r"); 
   FILE *fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r"); 
  

   FILE *fp3 = fopen("file3.txt", "w+"); 
   char c; 
  
   if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL) 
   { 
         puts("Could not find source files"); 
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
   }

   if (fp3 == NULL){
       puts("DNE");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
  
   while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) 
    fputc(c, fp3); 
  
   while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF) 
      fputc(c, fp3); 
  
   printf("Merged file1.txt and file2.txt into file3.txt"); 
  
   fclose(fp1); 
   fclose(fp2); 
   fclose(fp3); 
   return 0; 
}
```

It exits on DNE every time since file 3 is never created. I have tried using both w and w+ to no avail.

When using Errno, I get error no:13 permission denied. Even when running my vscode on administrator mode. Does anyone know why this is happening? I even removed my old code and copy pasted a generic answer from the internet but I still have these permission problems.

Comment: Other minor issue: `char c;` --> `int c;` to distinguish the 257 different results of `fgetc()`.

Comment: `fopen()` can return `NULL` which is your cue to check `errno`. Since you don't do that and just YOLO along anything could be happening here, we don't know.

Comment: @tadman As OP has "When using Errno, I get error no:13 permission denied", your comment "Since you don't do that" is unclear.

Comment: Are you running the executable manually or using the IDE to run it?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Where that comes from this code is not clear. I didn't notice they buried the lede there, was just looking at the source.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah both, neither gives me results

Comment: Can you create `file3.txt` manually in the folder?

Comment: @tadman Agree, code speaks louder the code comments and accompanying text speaks least of all.

Comment: @AyoObaisi Simplify.  What does `int main() { printf("%p\n", fopen("file3.txt", "w+")); perror("x"); }` report?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i get "x: Permission denied
0000000000000000"

Comment: @Neil I can but the issue still persists

Comment: What directory are you running this in? Can you `touch test.txt` or equivalent on your OS?

Comment: Perhaps `file3.txt` exist (rad-only) and code is not attempting to create where expected.  Could try another name. Maybe an absolute path name?  `"/tmp/t.txt"`  It is a poser.

Comment: Turns out the only issue was that I was trying to do C in windows. Installed Linux and A vm and the code worked just fine. Thank you for all of the help @tadman

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Turns out the only issue was that I was trying to do C in windows. Installed Linux and A vm and the code worked just fine. Thank you for all of the help

Comment: @AyoObaisi I suspect it was not an OS issue, but a compiler issue.  What compiler were you using under Windows?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was using G++, I figured it was a compiler issue as well but I can compile things like hello world with no problem. I can read files as well. The problem comes when I have to create or write to a file. It just can't do that.